# How to make a new line for every space, except one?

Tags: shell, unix, if-statement, sh, tr

I have a text file like this:

```
 www.twitter.com,sev-pool,tiger lion,
 www.google.com,"http google-pool,,
 www.facebook.com,pool,usa mexico canada,
```

I want to make every space a new line except the space in **"http google-pool** in this example, because the `"` is *unmatched* on this line.

Is there a way I can do this without using the line number? Perhaps an **if** statement dependent on the **"** , or any other way?

I am using the **tr** command:`tr " " "/n"` but I am unable to omit the desired line.

Expected output:

```
www.twitter.com,sev-pool,tiger
lion,
www.google.com,"http google-pool,,
www.facebook.com,pool,usa
mexico
canada,
```

Comment: `tr  ' ' '\n'` Backslash , single quotes (or double the backslash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `awk` solution that works with your updated requirements (ignore lines with an unmatched `"`):

```
awk '/"[^"]*$/ { print; next } { gsub(" ", "\n"); print }' file
```

Note:

- The assumption is that the lines that contain an unmatched `"` should be excluded from the space-to-newline translation *as a whole*.

This yields:

```
www.twitter.com,sev-pool,tiger
lion,
www.google.com,"http google-pool,,
www.facebook.com,pool,usa
mexico
canada,
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '!/google/{gsub(/ /,"\n")}1' file

www.twitter.com,sev-pool,tiger
lion,
www.google.com,"http google-pool,,
www.facebook.com,pool,usa
mexico
canada,
```